# large file size

Tags: blend-files

Every time I try different BlenderKit textures, my Blender file size seems to become very large.  My file size is now 800MB after trying a number of floor and tile textures in BlenderKit.  Am I doing something wrong?  How do I reduce my file size?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may have gathered some textures and data that is not needed and would only be cleared if you close Blender and reload, but there is a way, in the outliner change to "Orphan Data" view:
[image]
There you should find a list of all the data, textures and such that are not used and with a click on **Purge**.
[image]
You are able to clear unneeded data.

Comment: In addition, consider saving a compressed file via File → Save As → Compressed checkbox.